# Woocommerce Integration in own wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I design my website in bootstrap.I am going to convert it into word-press now. Then I to integrate woo-commerce in my website as per my design requirements. I do not need the design of the product page and shop page that the woo-commerce provide. 
First is it compatible to my website and then I want to design the woo-commerce as I want. 
Give me suggestions and a little bit of guidance.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

copy any free woocommerce supported theme....
edit the style.css... theme names etc.
then go to woocommere plugin.... there will be a folder named 'templates', copy that to your theme folder...but change the name templates to woocommerce.

Now in your theme find header.php.... check how it is there .. place header portion of you HTML there.... similarly edit footer.php

Your theme will be somehow ready... now change each and every bits and pieces as per your need ;)

Comment: Will you please suggest me a woocommerce supported theme. because my theme is totally different from all the wocommerce supported themes. I searched alot. thanks.

Comment: WOOT is a woocommerce supported theme